# Difference between union and countable union

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Oddly enough, I didn't find existing question/answer about this. I want to know the difference because that's what makes $\sigma$-field different from field (i.e., the former is closed under countable union whereas the latter is closed under union). Why union doesn't imply countable union through induction?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150530/sigma-algebra-and-algebra-difference for example.

Comment: Ah I didn't know I should have searched 'algebra' instead of 'field'. thanks

Comment: If $\mathcal A$ is closed under (binary) unions and $A_n\in\mathcal A$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ then with induction it can be proved that $\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\in\mathcal A$ for every positive integer $n$. However it cannot be proved by induction that $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\in\mathcal A$.